# How do I modify the first value in each list / tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of lists / tuples, e.g.:

```
objects = [
 (1, "a", "foo"), # or I can make [1, "a", "foo"] instead
 (20, "bb", "bar"),
 (1231, "cde", "foo2"),
]
```

and now I want to modify the first value of each tuple (e.g., do a simple `to_string` conversion):

```
objects = [
 ("1", "a", "foo"), # or I can make [1, "a", "foo"] instead
 ("20", "bb", "bar"),
 ("1231", "cde", "foo2"),
]
```

Currently I create a completely new list:

```
objects_str = []
for object in objects:
   objects_str.append((str(object[0]), object[1], object[2]))
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it? I thought about using `namedtuple` but it looks like they're immutable as well. Another option probably is to use:

```
objects_str = []
for object in objects:
   object[0] = str(object[0])
   objects_str.append(object)
```

Note: I'm allowed to mutate the original object as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate through `objects` to modify it in-place with indices:

```
for i, (first, *rest) in enumerate(objects):
    objects[i] = str(first), *rest
```

`objects` becomes:

```
[('1', 'a', 'foo'), ('20', 'bb', 'bar'), ('1231', 'cde', 'foo2')]
```

Comment: Good use of unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the list in place:

```
for i, object in enumerate(objects):
    objects[i] = (str(object[0]), object[1], object[2])
```